# access flash light through Camera2 API Xamarin C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, flashlight, android-camera2

I know how to access flash light through Android.Hardware.Camera but now i need to access flash light through Android.Hardware.Camera2.

in java its simple like this:

```
cameraManager = (CameraManager) GetSystemService(Context.CameraService);
cameraManager.setTorchMode(mCameraId, true);
```

I don't know how to do this in C#.
Please help.

Comment: Thanx. But as i told you its Android.Hardware.Camera.
I want to code in Android.Hardware.Camera2 API.

Comment: And you have checked out the official Camera2 sample already? https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/android5.0/Camera2Basic

Comment: yes, I am checking it plus xamarin official APIs Guide but its NOT HELPING.

Comment: Using upper case is not helping either.  Good luck.

Comment: I wasn't trying to be funny.  It is rude to use caps.  No one can read your mind here.  We don't know what you have checked and what you haven't. It doesn't say in your question. You have even misspelled Camera in your question title.

Comment: I really apologies....i don't mean that.

Comment: OK, not a problem.